# Error 'subscript out of bounds' using eval()-function based on assign()-function in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, eval, paste, assign

I want to assign plots using function 'ggplot' to an object which I have created by function 'eval'. This object is nestled in a loop and therefore defined as a list. During each round of the loop, the plot should be saved as an element of the list using the variable 'list_pos'.

The aim is to create three different lists 'Graphs_A', 'Graphs_B' and 'Graphs_C' with each three different plots as elements saved. Therefore as a result I can call the plots of a specific subgroup, for example Group A, at once by just running

```
Graphs_A
```

The R-Code looks like the following. Here in my example, I always assign the same plot to the elements which, of course, isn't the case for my real data set.

```
###### Example #####

# Load packages

install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)

# Creating data

names <- c("A","B","C")

numbers <- c(1,2,3)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  y = c( 3, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 8)
)

# Loop to assign ggplot to elements of list

for(j in names){
  assign(paste("Graphs_", j, sep=""), list())  
  list_pos <- 0

    for(i in numbers){
      list_pos <- list_pos + 1
      assign(
      eval(parse(text=paste("Graphs_", j, sep="")))[[list_pos]],
      ggplot() + geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) # Plot depends in real data set on value of i
      )
    }
}
```

I always get an error 'subscript out of bounds'. I tried different things like redefine the list as

```
assign(paste("Graphs_", j, sep=""), list("X","Y","Z"))
```

But it didn't help to assign the plots to the elements of the list. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Forget that `parse` and `assign` exist. You won't have a valid use for them until you are much more experienced in R and they only enable you to write bad (inefficient, hard to understand or maintain) code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately I have to use them in order to assign values to objects which I haven't created before. Therefore as I know that is the only way to create a nested loop as mentioned in my post.

Comment: You don't have to and you shouldn't. Use a list.

Comment: But what is a good possibility to save three different plots in three separate objects in a nested loop?

Comment: Do not do that. Save them together in a list, or nested lists. There is absolutely no valid reason for creating separate objects with a loop.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it with a nested list.

Answer (score 0):

First, the line `eval(parse(text=paste("Graphs_", j, sep="")))[[list_pos]]` does not make sense: `parse(text=paste("Graphs_", j, sep=""))` yields a string and `eval` evaluates the expression. Thus you cannot subset...

You can work with `eval(parse(text=...))` but I recommend to use lists:

```
# Loop to assign ggplot to elements of list
Graphs <- list()
for(j in 1:length(names)){
  for(i in numbers){
      Graphs[[j]] <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))
  }
}
```

I don't know why you want to assign the plots to a list, but the code above runs...

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have already thought about your solution. But it doesn't work for me because I want to save the plot in different objects 'Graphs_' depending on the round of the loop before. So for example for the first round of 'for(j in names)' the plots are different in my real data set depending on the round of the loop 'for(i in numbers)'. Therefore as a result I wish to get three lists 'Graph_A', 'Graph_B' and 'Graph_C' containing three elements with three different plots according to 'for(i in numbers)'. So I can call the plots for different groups each at once.